Why tsconfig.json in agnular does not use proper export in package.json from library?
I got my library - "my-lib" and consumer application "my-app"
in package.json of my-lib i got exports:
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/my-lib.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/my-lib.mjs",
      "default": "./fesm2022/my-lib.mjs"
    }

In my-app ts.config
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]

When I will remove "default", "esm" I get error
None of the conditions in the package definition ("types", "esm2022") match any of the currently active conditions ("browser", "default", "es2015", "es2020", "import", "module"):

Is there any way to configure my-app to use for example only esm / esm2022? Looks like now it uses "default". I want to configure tsconfig in that way, that I will be able to use "esm" export.

Why is the usage of esm2022 so important to you? Why can't you just let Angular choose what's (probably) the best for you? Why do you want to mess around with the generated package.json? It's a very bad idea. Angular may update the package format at any time. With Angular v19 they are actually going to update it, which will break your setup.
